# Извлечь данные при парсинге Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

При парсинге я получаю ответ в таком виде:

```
{
    data: {
        type: 'match',
        id: 'ae825686-8a74-4363-a1d1-402d5a4207d5',
        attributes: {
            createdAt: '2018-11-20T17:06:52Z',
            titleId: 'bluehole-pubg',
            shardId: 'pc-ru',
            tags: null,
            seasonState: 'progress',
            duration: 1823,
            stats: null,
            gameMode: 'squad-fpp'
        },
    }
    included:
    [{
            type: 'participant',
            id: '0b1b8f78-bb3e-4c0a-9955-9fdf8e33e5b4',
            attributes: [Object]
        }, {
            type: 'participant',
            id: '85e74b88-125b-4529-8c3f-fd76bd43b9aa',
            attributes: [Object]
        }, {
            type: 'roster',
            id: '6db70dce-b056-4bed-8cc4-6521b83bea50',
            attributes: [Object],
            relationships: [Object]
        }, {
            type: 'roster',
            id: 'a35db9ae-e559-4474-b922-784e3221f484',
            attributes: [Object],
            relationships: [Object]
        }
    ]
}
```

Мне нужно получить данные с `inculded  type:'roster'` и содержимого объектов `attributes, relationships`. Как мне это сделать?
Я пробовал извлекать как массив данных `console.log(included[0]);` Получаю данные с `type: 'participant'`.
Затем пробовал так `console.log(included[{type: 'roster', relationships}]);` В ответ получаю сообщение `undefined`
Подскажите пожалуйста как получить нужные данные, 3-й день ломаю голову. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`included` - это массив. поэтому обращаясь к нему - по индексу: `included[0]` - вы получаете объект по индексу 0.

Соотвественно: 
пусть `jsonObj` - это тот объект, который отображен у вас в листинге;

```
var included = jsonObj.included;
var obj = included[0];
var type = obj.type;
var relationships = obj.relationships;
var itemRelationship = relationships[0];
```

т.к. не во всех объектах массива `included` содержится `relationships` - то там будет `undefined`

Comment: Хорошо тогда может есть смысл, запихнуть эти данные в массив и отсортировать их там ? мне для начала нужно проанализировать то что храниться в объектах attributes, relationships. Получив там нужные ID нужно найти их и отсортировать. Как лучше это сделать ? Ну с точки зрения специалиста как вы, и бо я только учусь, и мне важно ваше мнение и совет. Спасибо

Comment: Мне подсказали использовать Array.prototype.filter()! окей, применил отфильтровал, получил только **roster**. Но там есть продолжение в таком виде : `{ type: 'roster', id: '7b095048-6923-430a-ace8-5269b3148499', attributes: { stats: [Object], won: 'false', shardId: 'pc-ru' }, relationships: { team: [Object], participants: [Object] } } ]` И мне нужны данные Team, которые опять спрятаны за объектом

Comment: @Ethernets это уже другие вопросы. не связанный с основным. Вы спросили, как "достучатся" до данных - я вам ответил. Если есть дополнения, к основному вопросу -внесите правку в вопрос. Если ответ вас устроил - пометьте его, как принятый. Это не форум. Если у вас появились другие вопросы - задавайте их, как отдельные